# underscore js, isFunction

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In underscorejs

```
if (typeof /./ != 'function' && typeof Int8Array != 'object' && typeof nodelist != 'function') {
    _.isFunction = function(obj) {
      return typeof obj == 'function' || false;
    };
  }
```

why it is not only `return typeof obj == 'function';`?

what that `|| false` give us?

Comment: `|| false` will return false by default if the first or'd argument is falsy.

Comment: @Pointy No doubt. I was trying to think of a situation in which the left side would not be a function and couldn't come up with one.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1333), it *may* be a work-around for some cross-browser bugs. See line #1333: *"Optimize `isFunction` if appropriate. Work around some typeof bugs in old v8,
  // IE 11 (#1621), Safari 8 (#1929), and PhantomJS (#2236)."*

Comment: @Wondercricket Thank you. It helps.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thank you too.